# Creating a function that takes a list, creates chunks within the list in increasing size , and the reverses it

Tags: python

Creating a function that takes a list, creates chunks within the list in increasing size starting from 1, and the reverses it. Should be an inplace solution, without having a return statement.

What I have tried:

```
def backward_chunk(l, size):
    start = 0
    for end in range(len(l)%size, len(l)+1, size):
        yield l[start:end]
        start = end
```

Example:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> backward_chunk(l, 7)
>>> l
[1, 3, 2, 6, 5, 4, 7]
```

explained:

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] then broken into chunks
[(1), (2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9, 10)] then each chunk is reversed

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: why the function has a size parameter. I don't see why it is needed based on your description

Comment: Does not work as intended.

Comment: I can remove the size parameter if needed

Comment: Having `yield` is probably not in the spirit of the assignment. An "inplace solution" typically means you mutate the original list passed to the function. Also, this will probably be easier with a `while` loop. Something like `while start < len(l):`. You should be able to do this with the `start` and a `slice_length` variable that changes in the loop.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

you can do slice assignment on alist

```
def backward_chunk(L):
    n,N=1,1
    while N<=len(L):
        L[N:N+n+1]=L[N+n:N-1:-1]
        n+=1
        N+=n
for x in range(2,12):
    l=list(range(1,x))
    backward_chunk(l)
    print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

*Note:*
I changed the names of your parameters to be more clear: `l` → `lst`, `size` → `first_chunk_size`.

```
def backward_chunk(lst, first_chunk_size=1):
    start_pos = 0
    size = first_chunk_size
    while start_pos < len(lst):
        to = start_pos + size
        lst[start_pos:to] = reversed(lst[start_pos:to])
        start_pos = to
        size += 1
```

---

*The explanation:*

The command `lst[start_pos:to] = reversed(lst[start_pos:to])` reverses the current chunk in place.

The next two commands adjust the start position and the length for the next chunk.

---

*Tests:*

```
lst = list(range(1, 11))
print(lst)
backward_chunk(lst)       # The 2nd parameter has the default value 1
print(lst)

print(40*"-")

lst = list(range(1, 13))
print(lst)
backward_chunk(lst, 3)
print(lst)
```

*The output:*

> ```
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
> [1, 3, 2, 6, 5, 4, 10, 9, 8, 7]
> ----------------------------------------
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
> [3, 2, 1, 7, 6, 5, 4, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8]
> ```